# Using table on a list of arrays in R

Tags: r, arrays, list

Let's say I have the following list in R:

```
my_list <- list(structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 25L)), structure(c(0, 
1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 
-1, -1, 0, -1, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 25L)), structure(c(0, -1, -1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 
0, -1, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 25L)), structure(c(0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 
25L)), structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 25L)))
```

That is essentially a list with 5 elements, each one being a numeric vector (the fact that every array has values ranging from -1 to 1 does not matter).

So what I want to find out is the most frequent array. If you look carefully, you'll note that elements 1 and 5 from the list are the same.

```
> all(my_list[[1]] == my_list[[5]])
[1] TRUE
```

Every other element is unique. So for this case, I'd have 4 unique arrays, and one of them is the most frequent (in this case, the one that occurs twice!).

I know that `unique()` works for this, giving me 4 unique elements for this case.

```
> length(unique(my_list))
[1] 4
```

So what I want to do is use `table` to find out the most recurring unique array. However, simply using `table` gives very strange results.

```
> table(my_list)
, , my_list.3 = -1, my_list.4 = -1, my_list.5 = -1

         my_list.2
my_list.1 -1 0 1
       -1  3 0 0
       0   0 0 0
       1   0 0 0
...
# a lot more strange output from here and on
```

What am I missing here? Should I not use table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `list` elements to index with `match`, get the frequency count on the match index and subset the `list` based on the `max` count

```
i1 <- match(my_list, unique(my_list))
tbl1 <- table(i1)
my_list[ as.integer(names(which(tbl1==max(tbl1))))]
```

Comment: Yea I thought about using some character related tool, but that does not look very efficient. Why should I spend so much time transforming numeric sequences to characters? That involves a lot of pasting and reducing and what not.

Comment: Update after your edit: great answer! Hope I helped you get that extra thought after my original comment!

Comment: @eduardokapp Initially I thought the paste method as it was the first idea.  When you probed, I thought a little harder :=)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one with `toString`?

```
table(sapply(my_list, toString))
```

which gives

```
0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0
                                                                                1
 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0
                                                                                1
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0
                                                                                2
0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0
                                                                                1
```